# Mapping a list of items in an array to a function parameter

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, performance, javascript-objects

I have an angular controller and service.

The controllers calls the service, and passes some data and an endpoint.

My service performs the http request, however i am trying to refactor my code so that i pass in an endpoint from my controller, and my service tries to match the endpoint from a list of array.

Controller:

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, myService) {

    $scope.buttonClick = function(endpoint) {
        myService.postAction(endPoint, $scope.postData)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                console.log("success");                   

            })

            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

               console.log("error");                    

            });
    }
```

MyService:

```
app.factory('MyService', function ($http) {

    var endPoints = [
        'cart/cartDetails',
        'customer/addressInfo',
        'payment/ShippingInfo',
    ]

    return {
        postAction: function(endPoint, postData) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: endPoint,
                data: postData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Depending on what button is clicked via `$scope.buttonClick`, any of the endpoints are passed, e.g.

```
<button ng-click="buttonClick('ShippingInfo')>Shipping</button>
<button ng-click="buttonClick('addressInfo')>Address</button>
<button ng-click="buttonClick('certDetails')>Cart</button>
```

Comment: 1. You can define endPoints as an object for the current scenario and use url: endPoints[endPoint] 

2. Or pass array index from button buttonClick(1) and use url: endPoints[endPoint]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your endPoints should be object

```
app.factory('MyService', function ($http) {

    var endPoints = {'certDetails': 'cart/cartDetails','addressInfo': 'customer/addressInfo','ShippingInfo': 'payment/ShippingInfo'}


    return {
        postAction: function(endPoint, postData) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: endPoints[endPoint],
                data: postData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: This will not work endPoints['ShippingInfo'] will be null

Comment: @vpsingh016 - thanks... Any benefits of using this over the answer below?

Comment: I don't see any benefits of doing like that, because in-future may be your endpoints get extended or you it may be configurable then it will not help you, coz then you have to add more object keys in return value also. Also size of your code will also get increased. Ideally there should not be anything hard-coded.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest not to do that, cause controller in that case need to know at least key of the url endpoint
It would be much better to have the following, your factory code:

```
var endPoints = {'certDetails': 'cart/cartDetails',
                 'addressInfo': 'customer/addressInfo',
                 'shippingInfo': 'payment/ShippingInfo'}


return {
    postCertDetails: post(endPoints['certDetails']),
    postAddressInfo: post(endPoints['addressInfo']),
    postShippingInfo: post(endPoints['shippingInfo'])
};

function post(endpoint){
    return function(postData){
        return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: endpoint,
            data: postData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        });
    }
}
```

usage in controller

```
service.postCertDetails({...your data...});
```